# Setting Django with virtualenvironment on an Apache

Tags: python, django, apache

I just want to know if you really need to put this code in the **wsgi.py** when you want to deploy in apache with your django virtual environment

```
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("/path/to/venv")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))
```

This is not mentioned in the Django docs. However my virtualenv seems not to be used whenever I load my django page on the browser and of course throws a 500 error because my installed packages is not available

Here is my apache conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName ai-labs.co

        ServerAlias www.ai-labs.co
        ServerAdmin admin@ai-labs.co
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ai-labs.co/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/html/ai-labs.co>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /static /var/www/html/ai-labs.co/static
        <Directory /var/www/html/ai-labs.co/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /static /var/www/html/ai-labs.co/media
        <Directory /var/www/html/ai-labs.co/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/html/ai-labs.co/ai_labs_website>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess ai-labs.co python-path=/var/www/html/ai-labs.co:/var/www/html/.virtualenvs_copy/ai-labs-website-pure-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup ai-labs.co
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/ai-labs.co/ai_labs_website/wsgi.py process-group=ai-labs.co

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you configure mod_wsgi correctly, no you don't. Read:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/using-python-virtual-environments-with.html